# How to get cmap to work in an iterable fashion within three for loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm building a set of graphs for every variable pair for each third variable, eg:

```
pressures = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0]
thicknesses = [0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0]
velocities = [600.0, 700.0]

for velocity in velocities:
    for thickness in thicknesses:

        fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
        cmap = plt.get_cmap('rainbow')

        for pressure in pressures:
            colors = iter(cmap(pressure/len(pressures)))

            try:
                ax.plot(x, y, label='{} mbar'.format(pressure), color=colors) #where (x, y) are variables decided earlier in the try loop
            except TypeError:
                continue

        ax.plot()
        ax.legend()
        plt.show()
```

This builds a graph with the data I want, but I can't get the color map to work. I'm trying to get it to show the same color for each pressure in each iteration of thickness/velocity pair.

Comment: What is `iter()` here? If you leave that out you should get the desired result if I understand the problem correctly.

Comment: Without `iter()` all off the lines are colored red, there seems to be no variation.

Comment: Using `iter()` you should get a `ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument` error. Without `iter`, you should get a plot [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJ2Ju.png). You may of course post a [mcve] to verify.